# Django. Ссылка на фаил

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.
Суть такова: есть н-ое кол-во объектов с полями(текст/цифры) и файлом.

```
class Karto(models.Model):
    idname = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
```

хочу отобразить данные по одному из объектов(view):

```
def docsupdocs(request, idname):
    args = {}
    args['myq'] = Karto.objects.get(idname=idname)
    ...
    return render_to_response('self_docsup.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(reqeust))
```

шаблон:

```
...
{{ myq.idname }}
{{ myq.datecreated }}
...
<a href="{{ myq.file }}">FILE</a>
```

проблема в том, что ссылка не открывает/скачивает ничего.
ссылка /uploads/file.txt
я думаю проблема в моих кривых настройках:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ ('static', 'C:/Python34/DocSup/static'), ]
```

file лежит в C:/Python34/DocSup/static/uploads/uploads/file.txt

еще ВАЖНЫЙ момент: в url не прописан путь к media...
делал как в документации

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

но у меня с этим ничего не работало и я убрал ...
ВОПРОС. Господа, что мне нужно добавить чтобы ссылка открывала документ?

Comment: мне кажется, или файл должен лежать не C:/Python34/DocSup/static/uploads/uploads/file.txt, а C:/Python34/DocSup/static/uploads/file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас есть небольшая неточность:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
```

MEDIA_ROOT указывает на C:/Python34/DocSup/static/uploads/
Плюс добавляется еще один uploads/, если в upload_to указан относительный путь.
Соответственно все грузится в C:/Python34/DocSup/static/uploads/uploads/

А ссылка {{ myq.file.url }}.

```
...
{{ myq.idname }}
{{ myq.datecreated }}
...
<a href="{{ myq.file.url }}">FILE</a>
```

Тогда получите /uploads/uploads/file.txt

Соответственно, подправьте модель так:

```
class Karto(models.Model):
    idname = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='', null=True, blank=True)
```

Или так:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Karto(models.Model):
    idname = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, blank=True)
```